# Web application that creates RSS feeds for any website

Tags: gratis, web-apps, rss

I'm looking for a web application that tracks changes on websites and provide them as RSS feeds. The detection of site / site-part structure can be semi-automatic, but should not be too time-consuming.

Optimal would be

- a free version, which is not too limited in terms of feed number and query interval or
- a one-time purchase application or
- a self-hosted tool

Comment: With automatic/semi-automatic tools, you'll certainly get at least some false positives from other than actual content changes. Just saying.

Comment: Which [RSS variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Variants) do you mean? Or is it "feed" in general (no matter which format), which would include [Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. It would be nice if my current reader (Feedly) supports the format.

Comment: You should give us some restrictions, "anything goes" or "too basic" requirements are no good since almost everything available would fit. If you already had experiences with something write what you liked/didn't like as requirements of your question.

Comment: @Braiam: I've tried page2rss few days now to see whether it fits. When I make some more experiences leading to advanced requirements, I'll come back on this.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. E.g. "not too limited" is far too subjective (fixed numbers of limits like "at least X feeds" are a better fit). Also, as already pointed out by unor: which formats? Should it just track "single pages", or is it supposed to "recurse"? What OS/... shall it run under?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several services that allow you to monitor sites without feeds.

I have used [page2rss](http://page2rss.com/) before and it doesn't have any kind of limitation. Google recommended that folk who were using its page migration option before move over to it - it's fairly simple

[image: Page RSS Search]

You simply put the URL in, and it converts it to a RSS feed. It does get a bit confused between minor and major changes on occasion, but it's a fairly robust site that dosen't *miss* anything major

Other paid services like [Feedity](http://feedity.com/) exist.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more about what the two recommendations you list can in terms of features? Why do you think they are great? How is the interface of them?