# A free web service to create an RSS feed from a page

Tags: rss, monitoring

I am looking for a free web service similar to [Change Detection](http://changedetection.com/) or [page2rss](http://page2rss.com/) that can create an RSS/ATOM feed from any page that does not provide a feed by itself. I am asking for an alternative to Change Detection and page2rss because these two are not capable of distinguishing between minor and real changes on a page. That is, with these services I often get an RSS feed update even if just one number changes, the page date is updated or a few words are added.

Do you know of any other web service that handles the recognition of changes better?

Comment: Must it be RSS or is Atom also allowed? If RSS, does the variant matter?

Comment: Thanks unor. Forgot to mention. Both RSS and Atom is fine. The variant does not matter as far as importing the feed into a feed reader is concerned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web application that creates RSS feeds for any website](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/295/web-application-that-creates-rss-feeds-for-any-website)

Comment: @JensPiegsa The recommended application there is page2rss which I already excluded here because it does page monitoring insufficiently, sending out alerts even for insignificant website changes that are not of interest.